# Â appearing in HTML email

Tags: php, email, utf-8

I'm sending a PHP email using:

```
mail($email, $subject, $message, $header);
```

I layout the message like this which includes some tables with prices like this:

```
$message = <<<EOF

<td style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding-bottom:4px; padding-top:4px; padding-right: 10px; text-align:right;\">£</td>

EOF;
```

On certain email clients the £ appears as Â£.

I understand this is to do with character formatting. But how do set UTF-8 character set when sending a PHP email in this way?

TIA

Comment: Searching `php utf-8 email` should help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you could use

```
&pound;
```

instead of the raw `£` character.

To set character encoding of email, set up the headers:

```
$from    = 'me@domain.com';
$to      = 'to@domain.com';
$subject = 'Subject';


$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$message = 'message';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks for including both methods. I've done both so hopefully that will be the end of that problem.

Comment: no problem, it should definitely resolve your issues! Also, with the headers set like that you can now send html emails rather than boring plain text!

Answer (score 3):

Use the HTML entity for the pound sign

```
&pound;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a more general solution than fin1te's:

```
$header = array(
    "From: {$email}",
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
);
$result = mail($email, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $header));
```